# Cannot find type Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.Models.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredential:

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-powershell

I am creating `Azure Active Directory Application` using `Azure PowerShell` in `Visual Studio Code` following this article https://sabin.io/blog/adding-an-azure-active-directory-application-and-key-using-powershell/ .

I have modified code to use `Az` module instead of `AzureRM` but getting exception

```
New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.Models.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredential]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

PowerShell

```
function Create-AesManagedObject($key, $IV) {

    $aesManaged = New-Object "System.Security.Cryptography.AesManaged"
    $aesManaged.Mode = [System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode]::CBC
    $aesManaged.Padding = [System.Security.Cryptography.PaddingMode]::Zeros
    $aesManaged.BlockSize = 128
    $aesManaged.KeySize = 256

    if ($IV) {
        if ($IV.getType().Name -eq "String") {
            $aesManaged.IV = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($IV)
        }
        else {
            $aesManaged.IV = $IV
        }
    }

    if ($key) {
        if ($key.getType().Name -eq "String") {
            $aesManaged.Key = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($key)
        }
        else {
            $aesManaged.Key = $key
        }
    }

    $aesManaged
}


function Create-AesKey() {
    $aesManaged = Create-AesManagedObject 
    $aesManaged.GenerateKey()
    [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($aesManaged.Key)
}

#Create the 44-character key value

$keyValue = Create-AesKey

$psadCredential = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.Models.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredential

$startDate = Get-Date

$psadCredential.StartDate = $startDate

$psadCredential.EndDate = $startDate.AddYears(1)

$psadCredential.KeyId = [guid]::NewGuid()

$psadCredential.Password = $KeyValue

$ApplicationURI = "https://xxx.xxx/xxxx"
New-AzADApplication –DisplayName “MyNewApp2”`

                         -HomePage $ApplicationURI `

                         -IdentifierUris $ApplicationURI `

                         -PasswordCredentials $psadCredential

$keyValue | out-file “c:\someplace\keyvalue.txt”
```

I need to know how to replace

```
 $psadCredential = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.Models.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredential
```

with something that is compatible and works in `Az` module

Comment: @JoeyCai no it doesn't work New-Object : Cannot find type [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.Models.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredential]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

Comment: `Import-Module Az.Resources
$psadCredential = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredent`. You need to import module first and then it will work well.

Comment: @JoeyCai. this did not work

Answer (score 0):

Try using `New-AzureRmADAppCredential` instead of `New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Resources.Models.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredential`.

Ref: https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/4491

**EDIT**__________________________________________________

If you choose to, You can enable aliases to work with the new AZ module and still use the old cmdlet names. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-2.4.0

But I think this maybe what you are looking for. `New-AzADAppCredential`

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadappcredential?view=azps-2.4.0

Comment: I am writing new powershell scripts using Az and AzureRM is old version so this does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

> Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredential

and it can be imported using

```
Import-Module Az.Resources
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code`$psadCredential = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredential` with the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/new-azadapplication?view=azps-2.4.0#parameters).

[image]

The result is as below:
[image]