# 'Type Not Found' error when creating a PSADPasswordCredential object

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-powershell, credentials

I'm getting an error when trying to create a new credential:

```
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "SuperStrongPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredential -Property @{ StartDate=Get-Date; EndDate=Get-Date -Year 2024; Password=$Password}
```

> New-Object: Cannot find type [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredential]: verify that the assembly containing this type is loaded.

I've imported these modules:

```
Import-Module Az.Accounts
Import-Module Az.Resources
```

Apparently this works for some folks but not for others:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56888631
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56894223

Unfortunately, I seem to have landed in the latter group.

I considered trying to load [the assembly itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.commands.activedirectory.psadpasswordcredential?view=az-ps-6), but I'm not finding its location on-disk.

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that, the object type used to create credentials is changed from **Az** module version **`7.x`** due to the **migration** from the Azure AD API to the Microsoft Graph API.

To know what **`Az`** version you have, make use of below Powershell command:

```
Get-InstalledModule -Name Az -AllVersions | select Name, version
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I ran same commands as you, I got **same error** even after importing modules as I'm using **`7.2.0`** Az version:

```
Import-Module Az.Accounts
Import-Module Az.Resources

$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "SuperStrongPassword" -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredential -Property @{ StartDate=Get-Date; EndDate=Get-Date -Year 2024; Password=$Password}
```

**Response:**

[image]

In that case, you can make use of below script to create **password credentials** in Azure AD application:

```
Connect-AzAccount
$AzureAdApp = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "testsriadapp"
$PasswordCredentials = @{
    StartDateTime = Get-Date
    EndDateTime = Get-Date -Year 2024
    DisplayName = "testsecret"
}
$Secret = New-AzADAppCredential -ApplicationObject $AzureAdApp -PasswordCredentials $PasswordCredentials
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, new application with **secret** created successfully like below:

[image]

**References:**

[Azure AD to Microsoft Graph migration changes in Azure PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/azps-msgraph-migration-changes?view=azps-9.7.1#new-azadappcredential)

[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ActiveDirectory.PSADPasswordCredential GitHub issue by **mikefrobbins**](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs-powershell/issues/2029)

Comment: As an aside, would you happen to have some insight as to [this problem](https://serverfault.com/q/1131298)?